# Remove space between chart js legend and chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

**How do I remove this space between the legend of this chart and the chart it self**

If I change the size it just breaks the diagram :(.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ucs8ybLg/14/

[image of the space between label and diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkYLB.png)

**Code for the diagram**

```
const config = { 
type: 'radar',
data: data,

  options: {
    elements: {
      line: {
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    },
    scales: {
        r: {
            suggestedMin: 0,
            suggestedMax: 10
        }
    }
  },
};

const data = {
  labels: [
    'Problemlösung',
    'Ausdauer',
    'Selbstständigkeit',
    'Zuverlässigkeit',
    'Reflexionsfähigkeit',
    'Teamwork',
    'Respektvoller Umgang',
    'Pflichtbewusstsein'
  ],

  datasets: [{
    label: 'Schüler',
    data: [10, 8, 6, 7, 5, 10, 5, 6],
    fill: true,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
  },
  {
    label: 'Lehrer',
    data: [8, 10, 7, 7, 3, 9, 8, 7],
    fill: true,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'
  }]
};
```

**Thank you very much for the help!**

Comment: That is not supposed to happen, which leads me to believe that there is some hidden element between the label and the chart. It would be nice to have a jsfiddle to test on (and to see if the problem can be reproduced in isolation).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ucs8ybLg/14/ thank you very much

Comment: I don't know the solution, but I think I have at the very least found the core of the problem. You have put the chart within `<div class="col-6 border charts">`. If I remove that div, the size of the chart blows up. I think the chart is created at full size, and then get shrunk down because of the css-classes you use. But it doesn't scale down in the right way. At the original size, the gap looks reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly define `options.aspectRatio` in order to change the `width` / `height` ratio of the chart.

```
options: {
  aspectRatio: 1.5,
  ...
```

> for more information, please consult [Configuration Options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#configuration-options) from the Chart.js documentation